# html submit a form without using POST

Tags: html, forms, post

I need to submit a form to another domain so i can't use POST

the form needs to submit to this URL:

```
http://www.mydomain.net/search.php?do=process&forumchoice[]=54&forumchoice[]=53&showposts=0&query=XXXXXXXX
```

Where `XXXXXXX` is the user entered value in a text field

how can i do this without using POST ?

Comment: use <form method=get>

Comment: Don't put method=post on the form. GET is default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form tag put 'GET' instead of POST

```
<form action="http://www.mydomain.net/search.php" method="GET">
```

Comment: Or just remove the method

Comment: Yeah that will work too, as I think the default is GET if no method is provided.

Answer (score 2):

Change the method attribute in the form, it would look something like

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.mydomain.net/search.php">
```

Just make sure to have all the required values inside the form, having name set, otherwise they won't hit the destination